# Are energy levels of metal nanoparticles discrete?

Tags: solid-state-physics, plasmon

I will start with the quote from the book:  "Plasmonics Fundamentals and Applications" by Stefan Maier. In the very first page he says "Even metallic nanostructures down to sizes on the order of a few nanometers can be described without need to resort to quantum mechanics, since **high density of free carriers result in minute spacings of the electron energy levels compared to thermal excitations of energy "kT" at room temperature**".

**My question**: Does the minute spacing of electron energy levels mean even though we are at nanoscale, these metal nanoparticles have continous energy levels. And how is comparing these energy levels to thermal excitations related to resorting to quantum mechanics?

Comment: Those closely spaced levels are still the result of quantum mechanics (as in larger crystals). But if the spacing is small compared to $kT$ one can deal instead with a density of states viewpoint which can simplify things.

Comment: So we can use the classical charge densities, maxwell eqns. etc. to solve the plasmonics problems if we approach it with Density of States viewpoint?